# How to show the equivalence between the centered and uncentered maximal function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show the equivalence between the centered maximal function
\begin{equation}
M_1f(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{|Q(x;r)|}\int_{Q(x;r)}|f(y)|dy
\end{equation}
(where $Q(x;r)=[x-r,x+r]^n$ is cube centered at $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and the uncentered maximal function
\begin{equation}
M_2f(x)=\sup_{Q\ni x}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f(y)|dy
\end{equation}
(where we take the supremum about cubes $Q$ centered the origin and including $x$): in other words, I want to show
\begin{equation}
c(n)M_2f(x)\leq M_1f(x) \leq c'(n)M_2(x).
\end{equation}
(where $c(n)$ and $c'(n)$ are constants depended only on the dimension $n$.) I have already shown the left inequality sign but I cannot show the right.

Prease show me how to prove this.

Comment: I think the right is easier than the left since you can take $Q = Q(x;r)$, and so $M_2 \geq M_1$.

Comment: I think that if you want $Q$ to be centered at the origin, then you have to integrate $|f(x-y)|$. Otherwise you can just require $Q$ to be a cube containing $x$.